# SearchReplace Plugin in TinyMCE 3.5.10 doesn't work with IE11

Tags: javascript, search, replace, tinymce

I was facing issues with IE11 on TinyMCE 3.4.8 so I upgraded to 3.5.10 and I see that all of the IE11 related issues have been solved there. Only 1 issue is that the SearchReplace plugin is not working. I looked at the code and I found that they didn't solve this for IE11 and they just added the below piece of code (in `searchreplace.js`).

```
if (tinymce.isIE11 && !window.find) {
    ed.windowManager.alert("This feature is not available in IE 11+. Upgrade TinyMCE to 4.x to get this functionallity back.");
    return;
}
```

I don't want to upgrade to 4.x. How can I make searchreplace plugin work in IE11 without upgrading?

Comment: +1 thanks for this info, a solution would be great to know for me too

Comment: No progress on this so far. I found that in IE11 Microsoft has replaced [`selection` object with `getSelection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535869(v=vs.85).aspx). I tried using the new method but still was unable to solve it. `findText` and `createRange` were also giving errors. If you get free time can you go through it and see what's the culprit? Thanks.

Comment: I already fouind outthe same and tried to change it as you did, but it didn't work. My thoughts about this are that moxycode refused to implement this funtion for IE11 in tinymce3 because of the time it would consume.

Comment: Same. They solved all IE 11 issues in 3.5.10, they just left this one. I guess they want people to upgrade to 4.x. BTW I saw that CKeditor guys have solved this issue using the new function (getSelection) but I didn't get time to go through their architecture and code. So the solution is there, need to see how to apply that in TinyMCE.